# How does an Apache server handle the PHP upload_size_max / post_size_max parameters?

Tags: php, apache

I've been implementing a simple image upload plugin and I would like to limit (server-side) the size of the file uploaded by the client in order to avoid resources abuse. I defined the limit as follows in my php.ini file:
upload_size_max = 2M
post_size_max = 2M

Now even though these limits are enforced by the Apache server, I notice that the progress bar in the browser does reach 100% when I'm trying to upload a 4M picture. The picture won't get uploaded, but it looks as if the server is processing the whole 4M.

My question is: why is Apache still processing the whole 4M before reaching the conclusion that it cannot accept a 4M file? Or maybe Apache is not processing the whole 4M but still the browser sends everything out (all the packets) and the last packets get ignored by the server?

Thanks for your inputs on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP limits are not enforced by Apache. They are enforced by PHP.

Apache also has its own limits. These are generally set in httpd.conf and the affiliated configuration files.

If you set the Apache limits more strict than the PHP limits, The Apache limits are limiting you.

I guess what you are experiencing is that Apache is accepting the whole uploaded file. Probably because the Apache limit is allowing you to. After upload is complete, Apache passes the request and the file to PHP, which then rejects it.

Comment: There is no way that PHP controls the server limits? If you do not mind, please provide some resources... tnx!

Comment: @MeNa : That is not what I meant to say. I'm not sure about that. Maybe it is possible for PHP to communicate with Apache or maybe not. But what I meant to say was: PHP has its own configs/settings and the web server (Apache or even IIS) has its own configs/settings. And that those exist side by side. Increasing a max file size for example, needs to be done on both sides.

Comment: It seems like regarding the max upload / post sizes, these parameters are strictly handled by php (not server related), which kind of makes sense this is not purely connection-related. Still curious to know what Apache config parameter would allow me to circumvent this and kill the connection after x Mb have been processed within a certain "request" or "time" or whatever unit would be  useful for that purpose.

Comment: @Julien Try looking at the LimitRequestBody http://linuxpoison.blogspot.nl/2010/06/limit-file-upload-size-on-apache.html Not sure though if Apaches default reaction would be to kill the connection or to just let the upload finish before giving 500 / 503.

Comment: In fact, I found out that using the directive LimitRequestBody allows you to put a limit on the body of a http request to Apache. This happens to be a very good proxy for my purpose ...